# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog' in jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

```
I have a problem of implementing the jQuery Dialog as Modal Form.



$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add-newItem")
           .button()
           .click(function () {
               alert('a');
               debugger;
               $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
           });
});




Here execution is hitting the method and displays "Alert" as per  the code. After the it comes   to debugger and when I use "F10" it tries to execute the  "$("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
```

" and getting the error below...

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

I have properly given refence to the jQuery as below

```
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="../../Content/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"               type="text/css" />


What could be the problem. If check using F12 of IE9 of my displayed page, I can list out the Dialog method from the script libray. but these are not vailable for the "$("#dialog-form")
```

regards,

Vinu

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `<div id="dialog-form" />` ? Make sure the div element is present.

Comment: Yes I have the basic problem is this when I look at the Immediate Window, I get


$("#dialog-form")[0].innerHTML
"

 <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required !!!</p>

 <form>

 <fieldset>
  <label for="countryId">Country Id</label>
        <input id="countryId" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" name="countryId" readOnly="readonly" value="0" type="text">
                  
 </fieldset>

 </form>

"

But when looked for 

$("#dialog-form").dialog('open')
Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Comment: Do you have the html code? Or URL to the page? What if you do alert($("#dialog-form").html())?